# How to turn vector into Matrix indices in R

Tags: r

How do I efficiently turn a vector into a matrix so that the values of the vector determine the column and the element ordering determines the row, and the value assigned at those indices are determined afterwards.

```
X <- c(1,2,3,1,1,3)
Y <- 1:6 
Z <- myfun(X, Y)

Z ## returns matrix
# 1  NA NA
# NA 2  NA
# NA NA 3
# 4  NA NA
# 5  NA NA
# NA NA 6
```

I am looking for a one-liner better than my for loop

```
Z0 <- X %o% rep(NA, length(unique(X)))

for(i in 1:length(Y)){  Z0[i, X[i]] <- Y[i] }
```

Comment: If you load the `Matrix` package, you could represent this as a sparse matrix - `sparseMatrix(i=seq_along(Y),j=X,x=Y)`

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

See the example:

```
X <- c(1,2,3,1,1,3)
Y <- 1:6

myfun <- function(X, Y) {
  Z <- matrix(NA, length(X), max(X))
  Z[cbind(seq_along(X), X)] <- Y
  Z
}

Z <- myfun(X, Y)
Z
```

Comment: That is better than my for loop, but I am looking for a one-liner.

Comment: @Jordan what a weird requirement to need a one-liner. What's wrong with two lines?

Comment: Nothing wring per say. But when code can be made concise it is often made more efficient. For example, using `tcrossprod` instead of a loop. Maybe the same logic applies to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on a one-liner, then @djhurio's answer can be converted to

```
replace(matrix(NA, length(X), max(X)), cbind(1:length(X), X), Y)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA    2   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA    3
# [4,]    4   NA   NA
# [5,]    5   NA   NA
# [6,]   NA   NA    6
```

Comment: Neat. And `replace` is literally just `x[list] <- values; x`, so it is @djhurio's answer, just with a convenience wrapper.